# How to query multiple columns against a single array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model:

Message.rb: sender_id, receiver_id, created_at

I would like to find all messages where the sender_id and receiver_id are both within an array of ids [1,4,41,543,312,62,234]. I would then like to group all the messages by the pair (sender_id & receiver_id) ordered by created_at.

Is this the right way to write the query? I am looking for an optimal solution here.

```
Message.where("sender_id IN ? AND receiver_id IN ?", @ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:-

```
Message.where("sender_id IN (?) AND receiver_id IN (?)", @ids, @ids).order("created_at ASC")
```

Comment: Thanks but does that group by sender_id and receiver_id before the order by created_at?

Comment: No it will not group your records.

Comment: Try Message.where("sender_id IN (?) AND receiver_id IN (?)", @ids, @ids).group("sender_id,receiver_id").order("created_at ASC")

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it errors with column "messages.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function